# Беда с кавычками при запросе по средствам Delphi из БД mySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, экранирование

Вычитал на одном форуме, что избегания попадания кавычек из БД, лишь прибегать к функции `StringReplace` и иного пути, какого-нибудь хитрого экранирования, я не нашёл.

Пример:

```
 ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('SELECT `number`, `family`, `name`, `patronymic`, `job` ');
 ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('FROM `users` ');
 ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('WHERE `job` = :job ');

 ADOQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('job').Value:= Edit1.text; //тут попадают кавычки.
```

Естественно ошибка.

Пример рабочего запроса в mySQL выглядит так:

```
WHERE `job` = 'Детский Сад "Солнышко"'
```

Предлагали сделать такое:

```
ADOQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('job').Value:= StringReplace(Edit1.text, '"', '""', [rfReplaceAll]);`
```

Но не помогло, так как в запрос идёт уже две кавычки.

Вопрос в том, как "обернуть", оформить вот такой рабочий запрос, из кода Dephi?

```
WHERE `job` = 'Детский Сад "Солнышко"'
```

Заранее благодарю за внимание к вопросу.

---

### **!!! P.S.**

**Извиняюсь за свою невнимательность!!!**
Я сам недоглядел и поставил:

```
ADOQuery2.Close;
ADOQuery2.SQL.Clear;
frxReport1.ShowReport();
```

Т.е. в Report естественно ни чего и не шло!
Вопрос решён - с использованием параметра всё будет работать!

Comment: Что находится в `Edit`.Text` и какую ошибку Вы получаете? Первый пример абсолютно рабочий и всякий `StringReplace` и подобное - не нужно

Comment: В чём проблема с кавычками? Зачем их экранировать в параметризованном запросе?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov прав, если не использовать параметры, а подставлять самому выражения в запрос, тогда будет возникать ошибка. Если же использовать параметры - все прекрасно работает.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov - действительно вы правы, просто мозг закипает иногда и не видит объективного. в `P.S.` к вопросу описал свой недогляд.

Comment: @vp_arth - мой мозг закипает иногда и не видит объективного. в `P.S.` к вопросу описал свой недогляд. Спасибо за то что вдохновляете к работе!

Comment: @I_CaR Мораль: **ВСЕГДА** указывайте какая ошибка возникает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте функцию `QuotedStr` или `AnsiQuotedStr` из стандартного модуля `SysUtils`. Они как раз для этого и предназначены.

> A Quote character is inserted at the beginning and end of S, and each
>   Quote character in the string is doubled. To remove the quotes from a
>   quoted string, use the AnsiDequotedStr routine.

На выходе функции получится такая строка:

```
AnsiQuotedStr('Детский Сад "Солнышко"', '"');
```

> Детский Сад "Солнышко" > "Детский Сад ""Солнышко"""

Comment: У меня на выходе должна получиться строка запроса в БД, результаты работы которой пойдут в отчёт FastReport. И вот получая строку для запроса, по вашему примеру запрос в БД пойдёт - `"Детский Сад ""Солнышко"""` и естественно такой записи MySQL не найдёт.

Comment: @I_CaR Это вы теоретизируете или проверили?

Answer (score -1):

Странно, prepared statements должны работать без экранирования. Одну кавычку можно заменить тремя, тогда должно работать.

```
ADOQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('job').Value:= StringReplace(Edit1.text, '"', '"""', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: Заменил, но это же идёт в сам запрос. Те в запрос пошло `Детский Сад """Солнышко"""`, естественно такого нет в БД.

Comment: Ну так попробуйте. Должно получаться `Детский Сад """Солнышко"""`

Comment: Первое предложение верно. А дальше какая-то ересь. К чему эти тройные кавычки внутри строкового литерала?

Comment: @vp_arth Я когда использовал эти ваши делфи, использовал 3 кавычки и получал одну в БД. Возможно, зависит от версии, но автор вопроса не соизволил ее указать.